# Thrust: How to directly control where an algorithm invocation executes?

Tags: cuda, cpu, gpu, reduce, thrust

The following code has no information that may lead it to run at CPU or GPU. I wonder where is the "reduce" operation executed?

```
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
...
// create iterators
thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(10);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first + 3;

first[0]   // returns 10
first[1]   // returns 11
first[100] // returns 110

// sum of [first, last)
thrust::reduce(first, last);   // returns 33 (i.e. 10 + 11 + 12)
```

Furthermore,

```
thrust::transform_reduce(
    thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(0), 
    thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(N), 
    MyOperation(data), 0 ,thrust::plus<unsigned int>())
```

Even though data is defined as thrust::host_vector, this function tries to be executed at GPU (compiler gives related errors, because the filename ends with .cpp). How may I make the code to run at CPU. Or should I look for another way to perform the same operation, e.g. not using counting_iterator?

Comment: I have tried retagging the counting_iterator as described in this page http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/DirectSystemAccess but compiler could not find the retag.h file, neither omp/memory.h file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, algorithm invocations like this execute on the device backend (i.e., the GPU in your case).

If you're using Thrust 1.7 or better, use the `thrust::host` execution policy to force an algorithm invocation to execute on the host (i.e., the CPU):

```
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

...

thrust::reduce(thrust::host, first, last);

...

thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::host,
                         first,
                         last,
                         MyOperation(data),
                         0,
                         thrust::plus<unsigned int>());
```

If you're using Thrust 1.6, you can retarget the invocations to the host by `retag`ging an existing iterator:

```
#include <thrust/iterator/retag.h>

...

thrust::reduce(thrust::retag<thrust::host_system_tag>(first),
               thrust::retag<thrust::host_system_tag>(last));

...

thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::retag<thrust::host_system_tag>(first),
                         thrust::retag<thrust::host_system_tag>(last),
                         MyOperation(data),
                         0,
                         thrust::plus<unsigned int>());
```

If you're using an older version of Thrust prior to 1.6, you need to pass `host_space_tag` to `counting_iterator` as a template parameter:

```
thrust::reduce(thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int, thrust::host_space_tag>(0),
               thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int, thrust::host_space_tag>(N));
```

Comment: Fantastic. Is there any help document about this? I use the NVIDIA's psg servers and it is unable to find execution_policy.h while compiling :( So it did not solve my problem, but it seems it is the solution. I compile with cuda_13 tag, because I get some errors when I compile with cuda_20 tag.

Comment: Thrust 1.7 ships with CUDA 5.5, which may not be publicly released yet. You can get it from Github in the meantime. Here's some documentation: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Direct-System-Access

Comment: At the NVIDIA's servers Thrust 1.5 is available. So I think there is no solution for this version? It already comes with Thrust 1.5 so should I try to have a local copy of Thrust and force to use it?

Comment: I'd just use a local copy, but I updated my answer to show what you can do with an old version of Thrust.

Comment: Yes, it totally solved the problem. Cool :) thanks very much!

Comment: I will try to publish a paper from my work/code, so I think your advice of using local copy of Thrust may also be a good choice.

Comment: cuda 5.5 RC (beta) is available to [registered developers](https://developer.nvidia.com/programs/cuda/register).